# How can I match exact word of text using reg.compile

Tags: python, regex

I want to find  a pattern (WITH RE.COMPILE) for the exact words like this,

Imagine such words [aether, altitude, aphelion, west]

which kind of capture word or word with punctuation, In a way that I can use it in spacy, I used this but it does not work

```
regex_patterns = [

re.compile(r'aether?,|altitude?,|aphelion?,|apside?,|apsis?,|ascension?,|autumnal equinox?,|east?.|eastward?,|eclipse?,|ecliptic?,|elliptical?,|epicycle?,|equinoctical?,|exquinox?,|fixed star?,|latitude?,|longitude?s|mean ecliptic?,|meridian?,|mobile star?,|node?,|nodes?,|north?,|octant?,|orbit?,|\borbital?,|\bparallax?,|\brays?,|\bretrograde?,|rise?,|sidereal?,|sidereal position?,|solstice?,|south?,|star?,|vernal equinox?,|west?,')
                                          ]
```

It would be nice if regex capture 'word' and 'word,' (word +punctuation)
like in this sentence

"west, can take a look"

the result should be

west,

Comment: It should be `,?` for an optional comma, not `?,`

Comment: How do you use it in spacy? Please clarify. Spacy has a tokenizer that processes text in a complex way. Are you trying to set exceptions to the custom tokenizer?

Comment: What do you consider the boundary of a word? Regex offers `\b` which is the transition from `\w` to `\W`, or from `\W` to `\w`. `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `\W` is the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

If we wish to match specific words, we might likely want to start with an expression similar to:

```
(aether|altitude|aphelion|apside|apsis|ascension|autumnal equinox|east|eastward|eclipse|ecliptic|elliptical|epicycle|equinoctical|exquinox|fixed star|latitude|longitudes?|mean ecliptic|meridian|mobile star|nodes?|north|octant|orbit|\borbital\b|\bparallax\b|\brays\b|\bretrograde\b|rise|sidereal|sidereal position|solstice|south|star|vernal equinox|west),?
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/V2SNtd/1/)

and then modify it by adding our desired punctuation in a char class:

```
[,:;\.]?
```

and our expression would likely become:

```
(aether|altitude|aphelion|apside|apsis|ascension|autumnal equinox|east|eastward|eclipse|ecliptic|elliptical|epicycle|equinoctical|exquinox|fixed star|latitude|longitudes?|mean ecliptic|meridian|mobile star|nodes?|north|octant|orbit|\borbital\b|\bparallax\b|\brays\b|\bretrograde\b|rise|sidereal|sidereal position|solstice|south|star|vernal equinox|west)[,:;\.]?
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/qEiVWC/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(aether|altitude|aphelion|apside|apsis|ascension|autumnal equinox|east|eastward|eclipse|ecliptic|elliptical|epicycle|equinoctical|exquinox|fixed star|latitude|longitudes?|mean ecliptic|meridian|mobile star|nodes?|north|octant|orbit|\borbital\b|\bparallax\b|\brays\b|\bretrograde\b|rise|sidereal|sidereal position|solstice|south|star|vernal equinox|west),?"

test_str = ("aether\n"
    "altitude\n"
    "aphelion\n"
    "apside\n"
    "apsis\n"
    "ascension\n"
    "autumnal equinox\n"
    "east?.\n"
    "eastward\n"
    "eclipse\n"
    "ecliptic\n"
    "elliptical\n"
    "epicycle\n"
    "equinoctical\n"
    "exquinox\n"
    "fixed star\n"
    "latitude\n"
    "longitude\n"
    "longitudes\n"
    "mean ecliptic\n"
    "meridian\n"
    "mobile star\n"
    "node\n"
    "nodes\n"
    "north\n"
    "octant\n"
    "orbit\n"
    "orbital\n"
    "parallax\n"
    "rays\n"
    "retrograde\n"
    "rise\n"
    "sidereal\n"
    "sidereal position\n"
    "solstice\n"
    "south\n"
    "star\n"
    "vernal equinox\n"
    "west")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: many thanks for your quick and correct responses, I used this based on your

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
'(word|other|foo|bar)+[\,\.]?'
```

that would **match** `word` and `word,`, `foo`, `foo,` and the other words with and without the punctuation chars `,`, `.` or others that you add.

Comment: I think you can omit the quantifier `+` for the capturing group as the group would contain the value of the last iteration. Group 1 will contain only `word` in `otherword` and the full match will be `otherword` https://regex101.com/r/XGTPNW/1

Answer (score 0):

```
label = "PLAN"
texts = texts
```

```
regex_patterns = [
re.compile(r'(\bAldebaran\b|\bAlphard\b|\bAntares\b|\bArcturus\b|\bBack of Leo\b|\bBeta Leonis\b|\bBeta Scorpii\b|\bBeta Tauri\b|\bBetelgeuse\b|\bcanis\b|\bCanis Minor\b|\bCor Leonis,7\b|\bCor Leonis\b|\bCor Scorpii,10\b|\bCor Scorpii\b|\bDenebola\b|\bdog\b|\bEpsilon Virginis\b|\bErichthonius\b|\bAldebaran\b|\bAlphard|\bAntares\b|\bArcturus\b|\bBack of Leo\b|\bBeta Leonis\b|\bBeta Scorpii\b|\b\Beta Tauri\b|\bBetelgeuse\b|\bcanis\b|\bCanis Minor\b|\bCor Leonis,7\b|\bCor Leonis\b|\bCor Scorpii\b|\bDenebola\b|\bdog\b|\bEpsilon Virginis\b|\bErichthonius\b|\bDenebola\b|\bdog\b|\bEpsilon Virginis\b|\bErichthonius\b|\bHeart of Hydra,8|\bHeart of Hydra\b|\bHydrae\b|\bKappa Geminorum\b|\bLambda Leonis\b|\bNeck of Leo\b|\bOrion\b|\bPalilicium\b|\bPolaris\b|\bPollux\b|\bProcyon\b|\bRegulus\b|\bSpica Virginis\b|\bTail of Leo\b|\bUrsa\b|\bUrsa Major\b|\bVindemiatrix\b|\bZeta Leonis\b)[:,]?')
]
```

As I faced with double punctuation (or inconsistent), I capture all the words like here:

```
\bCor Scorpii,10
```